# Compiler for Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, gcc, buildroot

Can Linux kernel be compiled with `gcc` configured for Linux executables (not bare metal)? I have noticed that Buildroot builds cross-compiler `arm-linux-gnueabi` to compile everything and became curious.
Or am I wrong and it builds bare-metal cross-compiler too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a Linux compiler can be considered as a "super-set" of a bare-metal compiler: it can compile both Linux userspace applications, and bare-metal applications (the Linux kernel, bootloaders, etc.).